# Create an object with reflection using lambda expressions

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, collections

We are using a lot of reflection by calling Activator.CreateInstance to create new objects in our code, but based on [this](https://vagifabilov.wordpress.com/2010/04/02/dont-use-activator-createinstance-or-constructorinfo-invoke-use-compiled-lambda-expressions/) article it's better using the compiled lambda expression to improve the performance.
So I created a static function that creates an intance of a class with lambda expressions :

```
    public static class ClassBuilder
    {

        private delegate T ObjectActivator<T>(params object[] args);

        /// <summary>
        /// This function will create a concrete object of type T
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">Base or concrete of object to return</typeparam>
        /// <param name="type">Concrete type of the object to create</param>
        /// <param name="parameters">paramters to give to the constructor</param>
        /// <returns>Instance of the concrete object</returns>
        public static T CreateInstance<T>(Type type, params object[] parameters)
        {
            if (type == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(type));
            }
            if (parameters == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(parameters));
            }

            // get the concrete types of given params
            Type[] typedArgs = new Type[parameters.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++)
            {
                typedArgs[i] = parameters[i].GetType();
            }

            // get the right constructor depending the arguments
            ConstructorInfo ctor = type.GetConstructor(typedArgs);

            if (ctor != null)
            {
                // create the activator
                ObjectActivator<T> createdActivator = GetActivator<T>(ctor);

                // return the concrete object
                return createdActivator(parameters);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Unable to find constructor with specified parameters.");
            }
        }


        private static ObjectActivator<T> GetActivator<T>(ConstructorInfo ctor)
        {

            Type type = ctor.DeclaringType;
            ParameterInfo[] paramsInfo = ctor.GetParameters();

            // create parameter of name args as expression (type of args : object[])
            ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object[]), "args");

            // create expressions for all the parameters of the constructor with the right type
            Expression[] argsExp = new Expression[paramsInfo.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < paramsInfo.Length; i++)
            {
                // get the type of the current parameter (parameter a position i)
                Expression idx = Expression.Constant(i);
                Type paramType = paramsInfo[i].ParameterType;

                Expression paramAccessorExp = Expression.ArrayIndex(param, idx);

                // Creates a UnaryExpression that represents a type conversion operation.
                argsExp[i] = Expression.Convert(paramAccessorExp, paramType);
            }

            // Creates a NewExpression that represents calling the specified constructor with the specified arguments.
            NewExpression newExp = Expression.New(ctor, argsExp);

            // Creates a LambdaExpression by first constructing a delegate type.
            LambdaExpression lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(typeof(ObjectActivator<T>), newExp, param);

            // Compile function will create a delegate function that represents the lamba expression
            ObjectActivator<T> compiledExpression = (ObjectActivator<T>)lambdaExpression.Compile();

            return compiledExpression;
        }       
    }
```

But after this implementation I tried to profile the 3 methods (Activator.CreateInstance, Inovke and Lambda Expression) by creating 1000 instances of an object. I was really disapointed of the result of the lambda expression.

Then I see in [that blog](https://vagifabilov.wordpress.com/2010/04/02/dont-use-activator-createinstance-or-constructorinfo-invoke-use-compiled-lambda-expressions/) that **"... it is important to remember that compilation should be performed only once, so the code should be carefully reviewed to avoid occasional recompilcation of lambdas"**.

So I added a cache that takes the ctor info as the key of the dictionary as following :

```
    // declaration
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<object, object> _activatorCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<object, object>();


    private static ObjectActivator<T> GetActivator<T>(ConstructorInfo ctor)
    {
        // check if the object is in the cache before creating it
        if (_activatorCache.ContainsKey(ctor))
        {
            return _activatorCache[ctor] as ObjectActivator<T>;
        }


        Type type = ctor.DeclaringType;
        ParameterInfo[] paramsInfo = ctor.GetParameters();

        ...

        // Compile function will create a delegate function that represents the lamba expression
        ObjectActivator<T> compiledExpression = (ObjectActivator<T>)lambdaExpression.Compile();

        // add the compiled expression to the cache
        _activatorCache[ctor] = compiledExpression;
    }
```

It improves a lot the performance but still not concluent.

Is there something I'm doing wrong ?

Is that a good way to cache the compiled expression with the ctor info as a key ?

Comment: You have `Type type` **and** `T`. Do those represent the same thing?

Comment: Not necessarily @MarcGravell , we can put an interface for T and type will represents the concrete type that implements the interface.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is still doing quite a bit of reflection *before* it gets as far as checking a cache - things like `GetConstructor` aren't free. Instead, you could perhaps look for something like:

```
public static T CreateInstance<T>(...) // ...=whatever args
{
    return CtorCache<T>.Ctor(...); // ...=whatever args
}
private static class CtorCache<T> {
    public static Func<..., T> Ctor; // ...=whatever args
    static CtorCache() {
        // TODO: assign CTOR - either through reflection code,
        // or as a fallback something like:
        // Ctor = args => Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }
}
```

This does *no* work in the general case - if the static constructor has competed, it just accesses the field and invokes the delegate. It even avoids a dictionary lookup (or rather: it pushes it to something similar implemented by the CLR itself).

Comment: Is that suppose to represent a cache ? If i understand, with what you suggest we'll always create an instance through reflection when call `CreateInstance<T>()`

Comment: @cheikhndiaye the idea is that in the static constructor you *decide* what to do, *perhaps* creating a `Func<...>` via expression trees, with `CreateInstance` simply the "if nothing better is possible"; hence the "TODO"